# Count the number of contiguous equal characters

Tags: c#, string, linq

I need to validate Serial numbers and one of the rules is that there are up to 5 contiguous equal characters allowed.

Example valid:

```
012W212222123 // 4x the digit 2 contiguous
```

Example invalid:

```
012W764444443 // 6x the digit 4
```

So I tried to get the maximum number of contiguous characters without success

```
int maxCount = "012W764444443".GroupBy(x => x).Max().Count();
```

Comment: Why not use a regex for this? `Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^(?!.*([0-9])\1{4})")`? If you need to check *any* chars, not only digits, use `.` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: To further clarify - `GroupBy` won't work, because it will group *all* characters in the string, not only those which are side by side. Unless you want create your own version of grouping which also takes position into consideration, correctly formed regular expression as Wiktor suggested, would be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a regex for a check to see if there are 5 or more consecutive digits:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^(?!.*([0-9])\1{4})")
```

If any characters are meant:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^(?!.*(.)\1{4})")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F!.*(%5B0-9%5D)%5C1%7B4%7D).*&i=012W212222123%0D%0A012W764444443&o=m)

The regex finds a match in a string that contains less than 5 identical consecutive digits (version with `[0-9]`) or any characters other than a newline (version with `.`).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
  -`(?!.*(.)\1{4})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the pattern is matched:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline
  - `(.)`  - Group 1 capturing any char but a newline
  - `\1{4}` - exactly 4 *consecutive* occurrences of the same value stored inside Group 1 (where `\1` is a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) and the `{4}` is a [range/bound/limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit)).

[C#](http://ideone.com/GBtVTl):

```
var strs = new List<string> { "012W212222123", "012W764444443"};
    foreach (var s in strs)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", s, Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(?!.*(.)\1{4})"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is to use this function:

```
public static int MaxNumberOfConsecutiveCharacters(string s)
{
    if (s == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));

    if (s.Length == 0) return 0;

    int maxCount = 1;
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == s[i-1])
        {
            count++;
            if (count > maxCount) maxCount = count;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    return maxCount;
}
```

Obviously, this is a lot more code than a regular expression. Depending on your knowledge of regular expressions, this may or may not be more readable to you. Also, this is probably more efficient than using a regular expression, which may or may not be important to you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little inefficient, but this works:

```
var max = 
    "012W212222123"
        .Aggregate(
            new { Char = ' ', Count = 0, Max = 0 },
            (a, c) =>
                a.Char == c
                    ? new { Char = c, Count = a.Count + 1, Max = a.Max > a.Count + 1 ? a.Max : a.Count + 1 }
                    : new { Char = c, Count = 1, Max = a.Max > 1 ? a.Max : 1 })
        .Max;
```

I tried with both inputs and got the right number of maximum repeats each time.